# How to recognise whether it's "haben Sie" ("you") or "haben sie" ("they")?

Tags: personal-pronoun

If somebody says

> Haben sie Deutsch in der Schule gelernt? *or*
>    Haben Sie Deutsch in der Schule gelernt?.

how I can recognise whether it's *you* or *they*?

Comment: In colloquial German, "sie" is often replaced by "die" if it doesn't mean "you". E.g., referring to a favorite band you'd often hear "Ich mag die gern" instead of "Ich mag sie gern". However, that doesn't work in a formal context.

Comment: How do you recognise in English if "you" is singular or plural? You do it using the context, and it's the same in German.

Comment: Du schaust Dich um. Stehst Du allein da? Singular. Seid Ihr eine Gruppe? Plural.

Comment: There actually are cases in which it is not clear if it's she or they. I see this in movies every now and then.

Answer (score 13):

In the written language, you can check if it is *Sie* (formal you) with a capitalized S at the beginning or *sie* (they), whose initial letter is lower case. But I am sure that you did not mean the written language.

In the spoken language, you cannot differentiate them without paying attention to the context. If the speaker talks about you, in this case, he/she means *Sie* (formal you), otherwise *sie* (they).

For example, if you are in a holiday and talk to a friend of yours about your family and your friend asks you,

> Werden sie auch hierher kommen?

it's clear your friend's referring to your family and not to you.

On the other hand, if your family is on holiday and you talk to a (not close) friend of yours about your family and their holiday, and your friend asks you,

> Werden Sie auch dorthin gehen?

it's also clear that your friend's referring to you and not to your family.

Answer (score 0):

In the spoken case you can only tell this from the context. If the context is about many people, then it means "they", otherwise "You".

In the written case: A lower case "sie" indicates "they", an upper case "Sie" indicates "You". But check the context anyway because of possible typing errors.

Comment: How does one recognize whether somebody says (as asked in the question) in the lower or in the upper case?

Comment: Danke für Ihre Erklärung, man

Comment: The question doesn't start with »*If somebody **writes** ...*«. It starts with »*If somebody **says** ...*« But nobody can *hear* if the spoken word should be written capitalized or lower case.

Comment: But "Sie" can also refer to many people: "you" (plural).